# Nodejs Sequelize recursive async/await

Tags: asynchronous, recursion, async-await, promise, sequelize.js

I'm struggling with a recursive loop and nested create/select statements. I'm receiving an object from a post request with the following structure:

```
 11.6042
 ---11.6042_01
 ---11.6042_02
 ---11.6042_02
 ---14x10-100
 ------14x10-100_01
 ---14x10-100
 ------14x10-100_01
 ---14x10-100
 ------14x10-100_01
 ---M10-DIN929_14020
 ---M10-DIN929_14020
 ---11.6042_05
```

Wanted behaviour: travel through the structure recursive, add record to Part table, self join with parent part, join with PartLib table, if no match present create PartLib record and match created record. Process next part.

The problem: part 14x10-100 occurs three times in the structure. I want to create a record for part 14x10-100 in the part_lib table and refer to that record three times. What actually happens is that for each 14x10-100 part a corresponding record in the part_lib table is created in stead of one create and two matches. If I run it again it will match like excpected. I suspect I'm lost in the promise/async await parts of the code.

Below the relevant code. I've removed some attribute mappings for readability. My thoughts behind it: I'm not returning new promises like normal in a async function since Sequelize already returns a promise. When creating a part I'm awaiting (or at least I think so) the partLibController calls to ensure that all matching/creating/joining is done before proceeding to the next part in the structure.

Thanks a bunch!!

**Recursive loop**

```
function parseChild(child, modelId, parentId, userId, level) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        partController.create({
            parent_id: parentId
            , name: child.name
        }, { id: userId }).then((part) => {
            resolve({ child: child, level: level });
            
            if (child.children) {
                child.children.forEach(grandChild => {
                    parseChild(grandChild, modelId, part.part_id, userId, level + '---');
                });
            }
        }).catch(error => { console.log(error); });
    }).then((obj) => { console.log(`${obj.level} ${obj.child.name}`); });
}
```

**PartController Create**

```
async function create(partBody, currentUser) {
    let { parent_id, name } = partBody;
    
    const match = await partLibController.match(name);
    let partLibId = null;

    if (match.length == 0) {
        const partLib = await partLibController.createFromPart(partBody, currentUser);
        partLibId = partLib.part_lib_id;
    } else {
        partLibId = match[0].dataValues.part_lib_id
    }

    return ModelAssembly.create({
        parent_id: parent_id
        , name: name
        , part_lib_id: partLibId
    });
}
```

**PartLibController Match**

```
function match(name) {
    return PartLib.findAll({
        where: {
            name: name
        },
    });
}
```

**PartLibController CreateFromPart**

```
function createFromPart(partBody, currentUser) {
    let { name } = partBody;
    
    return PartLib.create({
        name,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to AKX I've solved the problem: [hero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63141549/javascript-recursively-call-axios-get)

The problem was in the recursive call itself I suppose but here's the working code:

```
async function parseChild(child, modelId, parentId, userId, level) {
    const body = {
        parent_id: parentId
        , name: child.name
    };
    const ma = await partController.create(body, { id: userId });

    if (child.children) {
        for (const grandChild of child.children) {
            await parseChild(grandChild, modelId, ma.part_id, userId, level + '---');
        }
    }

    return;
}
```